# Parse multiple awk variables in a "for" loop bash

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, awk

I am trying to parse multiple awk variables into a for loop. I have a document that consists of multiple fields separated by a comma. Each field is capture by awk and I want to use these variables to create multiple instances of text in an additional file. I have used "while" to capture the variables, but this only runs once.

```
awk -F ',' '{print $1,$2,$3}' extensions.txt | while read var1 var2 var3; do
            echo " <item context=\"active\" type=\"\" fav=\"false\" mod=\"true\" index=\"0\">
            <number>$var3</number>
            <number_type>sip</number_type>
            <first_name>$var1</first_name>
            <last_name>$var2</last_name>
            <organization>Stackoverflow</organization>
            </item>" > test.txt
done
exit
```

Output for test.txt is:

```
        <item context=\"active\" type=\"\" fav=\"false\" mod=\"true\" index=\"0\">
        <number>123456789</number>
        <number_type>sip</number_type>
        <first_name>Jon</first_name>
        <last_name>Doe</last_name>
        <organization>Stackoverflow</organization>
        </item>
```

If I use a for loop, it won't retain the 3 variables seperately, but rather take the combined output and place it into a single variable.

Comment: The trailing `exit` is pretty pointless; the shell will exit anyway if you delete the line and it is the last (non-blank, non-comment) line in the script.

Comment: Note that each iteration of the loop clobbers the file `test.txt`.  Either place the output redirection after, but on the same line as, the `done`, or use append mode `>>`.

Comment: You should really show a few (say 3) lines of input, plus the desired output, plus the actual output.

Comment: Hard to format the comment, but multiple line echo with embedded quotes is much cleaner written with a heredoc.  eg`cat << EOF\n <item context="active...\nEOF`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `awk`. You can do it with `bash` itself by using `IFS` (Internal  Field  Separator).

Use this:

```
while IFS="," read v1 v2 v3 _
do
    echo "<item context=\"active\" type=\"\" fav=\"false\" mod=\"true\" index=\"0\">
    <number>$v1</number>
    <number_type>sip</number_type>
    <first_name>$v2</first_name>
    <last_name>$v3</last_name>
    <organization>Stackoverflow</organization>
    </item>";
done < extensions.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: I just tested it and it does work indeed. Thanks man appreciate it!!! :)

Comment: You might want to add a dummy variable at the end to catch any potential four words lines: `read -r v1 v2 v3 _ <<< "a,b,c,d,e,f"` Will assign `a`, `b` and `c` to `v1`, `v2` and `v3`, while `d,e,f` will be assigned to `_`.

Answer (score 3):

You could let Awk  do all the work. Awk does process line by line, so put the awk in a file and use `awk -f your_program.awk`.

Something like this should work:

```
{
    print "<item content=\"active\" type=\"\" fav=\"false\" mod=\"true\" index=\"0\">"
    print "<number>"$1"</number>"
    print "<number_type>sip</number_type>"
    print "<first_name>"$2"</first_name>"
    print "<last_name>"$3"</last_name>"
    print "<organization>Stackoverflow</organization>"
    print "</item>"
}
```